# Want these to be two separate columns, both are from different tables. I'm using concat to combine the original variables

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(employee.Firstname, " ", employee.Lastname, "  ", tickets.Status,"   ", tickets.Duration) AS 'EmployeeName and Time Duration'
FROM
    employee, tickets 
WHERE
    employee.idEmployee = tickets.Employee_idEmployee 
    AND Status = 'completed'
```

[image: 1]

Comment: And what is the question? Don't concat them and they will be in separate columns

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Could you describe the problem a bit more? What exactly do you want to achieve? Usually, examples help. What exactly doesn't work with your query? Please make sure to include enough details to your question so that others can reproduce it on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you need two separate concat statement , if I understand correctly :

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(employee.Firstname, " ", employee.Lastname) AS 'EmployeeName' 
  , CONCAT(tickets.Status,"   ", tickets.Duration) AS 'Time Duration'
FROM
    employee
JOIN tickets 
ON  employee.idEmployee = tickets.Employee_idEmployee 
    AND Status = 'completed'
```